# Не работает переключатель у `checkbox`

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: Должен получится такой результат (ползунок должен двигаться)]Не работает переключатель у `checkbox`. Остается активным только у первого где, в html задан `cheked`. В чем может быть ошибка?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //checkbox
  $.each($('.checkbox'), function() {
    if ($(this).find('input').prop('checked') == true) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'checkbox', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
      $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('active');


    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form action="#" class="block-form">
      <div class="block-form__title">Form style</div>
      <div class="block-form__input">
        <div class="checkbox">
          Первый выключючатель
          <input type="checkbox" checked name="namechekbox_1">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          Второй выключючатель
          <input type="checkbox" name="namechekbox_2">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-form__input">
        <div class="radiobittons">
          <div class="radiobuttons__item">
            Вариант 1
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="nameradio">
          </div>
          <div class="radiobuttons__item">
            Вариант 2
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="nameradio">
          </div>
          <div class="radiobuttons__item">
            Вариант 3
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="nameradio">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="button">Отправить форму</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: цель то какая всех этих действий?

Comment: сделать ползунок, который будет переключаться: если активен- зеленый, пассивен- серый, при том, что первый должен по умолчанию быть активным.

Answer (score 0):

Вот самое простое решение, взятое [отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

Конечно же вам нужно его кастомизировать под свою задачу

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```